# Crontab - day of month seems to override day of week?

Tags: linux, redhat, cron

I have five servers running an eventstore cluster. I want to run a crontab command on each one on separate days.

1. Run on Monday
2. Run on Tuesday
   etc

But I also want to run a different command on the fourth week of every month.

I set them up like this, thinking it should work - and checking crontab.guru confirmed what I thought should happen;

Machines 1-5:

1. 30 6 1-21 * Mon /first-command-to-run
2. 30 6 1-21 * Tue /first-command-to-run
3. 30 6 1-21 * Wed /first-command-to-run
4. 30 6 1-21 * Thu /first-command-to-run
5. 30 6 1-21 * Fri /first-command-to-run

Then a similar command on each for the Week 4 command:

1. 30 6 22-29 * Mon /week4-command-to-run
   (repeat DOW as above)

So for today - Friday the 19th, I wanted just machine #5 to run /first-command-to-run at 0630 and for the other four to do nothing.

I was fairly confident this would work as expected, but it seems *all five* machines ran /first-command-to-run this morning, instead of just Friday's machine.

None ran the /week4-command-to-run though, so the day of month falling outside of the 22-29 range is correctly preventing that.

I'm now wondering if by specifying the day-of-month range, this is causing cron to disregard the Day-of-Week. Could that be the case? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Os is Rocky 8.4

(Note: I'm aware and okay with the fact that the exact day-of-months might fall outside the strict weeks.)

Comment: Thanks to @archemar for the pointer. 

For anyone following, this will do as I expected:


30 6 1-21 * * [ "$(date --date='Today' '+\%a')" = "Tue" ] && /first-command-to-run

Answer (score 0):

according to `man 5 crontab` on ubuntu.

> Note:  The  day  of  a  command's  execution can be specified by two
> fields — day of month, and day of week.  If both
> fields are restricted (i.e., don't start with *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.

Please, do check your local crontab man page.

Comment: Gah, Don't know how I missed that. 

Thanks for the reply, that's definitely the issue. 

Looks like I'll need to do some smarter logic on the script itself.